# Project is unavailable

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

While loading the iOS project in visual studio, it says "install missing features" and shows project is unavailable. What is the issue here?

[Error is shown in this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yDbP.png)

[After reloading project leads to this popup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVOOZ.png)

Comment: It seems your install of Xamarin into Visual Studio is corrupted. Please check [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/troubleshooting/missing-vs-extensions/) for help on regenerating it

Comment: Did you rename your project or did you move it to another folder?

Comment: The project is there only. Its not moved and not renamed. @EJW

Comment: @Gerald Versluis I tried uninstalling and installing visual studio again, it did not wrked. Also I am using Visual studio 2015 which comes with xamarin.

Comment: Did you connect to the iOS build agent on your Mac?

Comment: What do you mean by iOS build agent? I haven't understood. I am using virtual mac and it has xamarin installed on it. However I am using visual studio that connects to my virtual mac. But as project is not loaded it is not connected with mac. @Gerald Versluis

Comment: Probably you already did it but did you try reload the project? You could also try to run vs17 as Administrator and reload it.

Comment: Reloading project gives popup with message, "The project will not be loaded unless you install missing feature.". I have added this image too in question just now. You can see it there. And I am running vs as administrator only. @EJW

Comment: Ok I think you don't have installed Xamarin (correctly). Start your visual studio installer again and check with features you've installed. Which version of visual studio do you use?

Comment: Ohk I will reinstall visual studio again. I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Reinstalling visual studio didnt worked. Do you have any other suggestions? @EJW